# How to construct a format string in C with a variable or repeating number of placeholders?

Tags: c

I want to write a hexdump function. Therefore, I want to use sprintf with a format string like

`"%c %c %c %c  0x%02X 0x%02X 0x%02X 0x%02X"`

and then use this string with characters (or bytes) in printf().

However, I want the user to specify the line width, i.e., the number of bytes to be dumped on each line.

How do I construct a format string that has the given width, i.e. a width of 2 results in a format string of `"%c %c  0x%02X 0x%02X"`...

Comment: Choose a language, C and C++ are different languages with similar syntex.

Comment: I've restricted to C, thanks @Sma.

Comment: @Sma I don't think that's a valid objection here. OP wants to use `sprintf()`, a function that is the same in both languages; C++ just imports the C headers with namespaces and other required minor changes.

Comment: If you did want to use C++-specific syntax, then there's `std::hex` and `std::setw()` from `<iomanip>`.

Comment: https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/tree/master/text-utils

Comment: googling "c hex dump source" yields lots of examples:
https://github.com/wahern/hexdump/blob/master/hexdump.c

Comment: What have you tried?  What part of building the format string is giving you trouble?  Building a format string shouldn't be significantly harder than building any other string.

Comment: @jamesdlin - I just wanted to know if there was any smart and quick way of doing it. I know I can just allocate a buffer and then do it the hard way in a loop.

Comment: @Shuzheng - your algorithm is wrong. Use loops instead :). It is not only the format string, you need to supply the values as well :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of constructing a format string using `sprintf()` only to use later with `printf()`, consider the following approach which is (basically) two passes over the input string:

```
void hex_dump(char *bytes, size_t bytes_len)
{
    const int DUMP_WIDTH = 16;

    for (int i = 0; i < bytes_len; i += DUMP_WIDTH)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < DUMP_WIDTH; ++j)
        {
            if (i + j >= bytes_len) {
                printf(" ");
                continue;
            }
            char ch = bytes[i + j];
            if (isprint(ch))
            {
                printf("%c", ch);
            }
            else
            {
                printf(".");
            }
        }
        printf("   ");
        for (int j = 0; j < DUMP_WIDTH && i + j < bytes_len; ++j)
        {
            printf("0x%02x", bytes[i + j]);
            printf(" "); 
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

The function will output `hexdump`-like output controlled by the `DUMP_WIDTH` constant. Also, the output is properly aligned.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to do like this:

I suggest to do like this:

```
void writeIntegersAsChar(char* str, int* source, int N)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < N; i ++)
    {
        sprintf(str + i, "%c", source[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This could use some fleshing out, and I agree that doing it 1 at a time is the simplest approach, but you might as well use `fprintf()`   Also using something like `isprint(c) ? c : '.'` is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

It is rather easy to construct such a format string.

However, the problem is **calling sprintf** with that format. There is no function in `<stdio.h>` that would let you pass in an *array* of arguments. Every single `printf` variant in the standard C requires you to decide the *number of arguments* at the compile time.

While it is possible to pass in *less* arguments, it doesn't help you with combined hex display such as

```
"%c %c %c %c  0x%02X 0x%02X 0x%02X 0x%02X"
```

and it gets rather tedious soon.

Unfortunately there is no easy way out - either you need to write your own *sprintf* variant, or use a loop instead.